# Programmatically determine the size of a SQL Server Compact sdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-ce

I'm running an ASP.NET MVC app, in shared hosting. My data is in a SQL Server Compact database "sdf" file.

I have a limited amount of diskspace. I'm worried that I'll go over that limit and my site will break. I can FTP into my account, and check the sdf file's size, but that is a slow manual annoying process.

So, during runtime, given nothing but the connection string, can I determine the database's size on disk?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637076/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-size-of-a-sql-server-database or http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/how-to-get-whole-database-size-using-C-Sharp-in-sql-server/

Comment: You could parse the connection string and read the file size on disk based on the file name

Comment: @Greg The SO link not so useful, but that blog article is very useful!

Comment: @JohannBlais No that's the point, in shared hosting I don't have such privileges (I think!)...

Comment: Since you are FTP-ing manually, you could use a .NET FTP client to do the same from the application :)

Comment: @hbob If you have shared hosting I doubt you have disk privileges.

Comment: @JohannBlais Yes we thought of that! It's sneaky but it works... Hope I can find something more robust though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(pathTosdfFile);
long fs = fi.Length; //your file size in bytes
```

btw, you can in your connection string restrict max size of your sdf file

```
Data Source=your.sdf;Max Database Size=256;
```

this will restrict grows over 256MB - default if I remember correctly 128MB

and path to your database should be like this:

```
 string path =   System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName
   (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\your.sdf;
```

Comment: Didn't think this would work for me. Then I discovered our shared host actually runs our app in full trust. So it works.